# How do I call jQuery's hide() method in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to hide an object using the jQuery method `hide()`, but it doesn't work.

I used console.log() to check the value of the argument in called function, so I know Im not doing right. But, i dont know how to make it work...

Here's what I have:

```
#------------------------Model------------------------


App.Monster = Ember.Object.extend({

name: "",
hp: 0,
isDead : false,

isDeadChanged: function(target, value){
    App.monstersController.kill(target);
}.observes('isDead')

});



#------------------------Controller------------------------




App.monstersController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({

content:[],

createMonster: function(name,hp){
    var monster = App.Monster.create({name:name});
    this.pushObject(monster);
},


kill: function(target){

    //I Want the selected object to hide by using Jquery hide method!!
    $('target').hide();

    this.removeObject(target);


},


#------------------------HTML FILE------------------------



{{#each App.monstersController contentBinding="App.monstersController.content" tagName="ul"}}
    <li>
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isDead"}}
        <label for="" {{bindAttr class="isDead"}}>{{name}}</label>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally bringing your DOM scripting patterns to Ember isn't going work, since Ember isn't about DOM manipulation it's about describing your application using objects. The DOM representation of your application will update automatically to reflect the state of its underlying data objects.

Ember.View tracks its visibility (and the visibility of its child views) with the `isVisible` property and will handle toggling the it's DOM representation for you. You should try to uncover the semantic object meaning of visibility for a given view context. For example, if you decided finished items in a todo list shouldn't be visible, you'd do:

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{view App.TodoItemView isVisibileBinding="item.isComplete"}} <a {{action kill item}}>Done!</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I didn't know Ember.View has isVisible property.Good to know that.

But, how can I hide the complete Task gradually in this case by using Jquery.hide(mseconds)?

Comment: Transitions like this are coming in 1.0

Comment: To achieve a fade effect, one thing to try could be using `classNameBindings` to add a css class when the `isComplete` property is set. Then you can use a CSS3 transition to fade it's opacity to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Don't quote `target`.

```
kill: function(target){   
    //I Want the selected object to hide by using Jquery hide method!!
    $(target).hide();   
    this.removeObject(target);
},
```

`$('target')` looks for `<target>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for you comment!

I took quotations off, but it still doesn't work.
Any other suggestions I should try?

Comment: What type of object is `target`? It needs to be a jQuery object, DOM element, or selector string for `$(target)` to work. Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Console.log showed this.

c {hp: "100", isDead: true, name: "MONSTER"}
__ember1355471385772: "ember502"
__ember1355471385772_meta: m
_super: undefined
hp: "100"
isDead: true
jQuery1720822808830300346: Object
name: "MONSTER"
__proto__: Object

Comment: And I got an error below.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined